# How to dynamically manipulate elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a predefined div and the corresponding CSS as below:

```
<div id="pin0" style="display: none" class="pin">
        <div class="comment">
            <div class="delete">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deletePin(this);">
                    <img src="/Images/RE/cross.png" style="border: 1px groove" width="16px" height="16px" /></a>
            </div>
            <textarea style="border: 0px; resize: both;" rows="3" cols="35" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="/Images/RE/03.png" />

.pin
    {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url('/Images/RE/ping.png');
        width: 32px;
        height: 16px;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    .delete
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 300px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .comment
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: auto;
    }
```

This will be the outcome:

[image]

Notice that this whole `DIV` is a hidden element which then allows user to clone them on double click via JQuery as below:

```
$("#clicks").dblclick(function (e) {
            var offset_t = $(this).parent().offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            var offset_l = $(this).parent().offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

            var newX = Math.round((e.clientX - offset_l));
            var newY = Math.round((e.clientY - offset_t));

            var newDiv = $('#pin0').clone();
            newDiv.attr('id', 'pin' + $("#clicks").children('.pin').length);

            $(newDiv).css('top', newY - 25);
            $(newDiv).css('left', newX - 10);
            $(newDiv).css('display', 'block');

            $(this).append(newDiv);
            $(newDiv).draggable();
        }
        )
```

As you can see, I've setting the ID by `'pin' + $("#clicks").children('.pin').length`. Now I'm wondering how to manipulate this particular element dynamically. I've tried the very manual way by hardcoding the ID as below but simply not working:

```
$("#pin1").focus(function (e) {
            alert("hello!");
        })
```

Comment: have you tried `newDiv.focus(function (e) {
            alert("hello!");
        })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your content is added dynamically so it is not accessible directly ,So you have to use Event delegation.

```
$("#clicks").on('focus','#pin1',function (e) {
        alert("hello!");
});
```

**Updated after OP's comment**

alert will come when you click on image

```
$("#clicks").on('click','#pin1 img',function (e) {
        alert("hello!");
});
```

alert will when you click on image contained in the id starting with  `pin`

```
$("#clicks").on("focus", "[id^=pin] img", function (e) {
        alert("hello!");
});
```

to alert id

```
$("#clicks").on("focus", "[id^=pin]", function (e) {
        alert(this.id);
});
```

or with img

```
$("#clicks").on("focus", "[id^=pin] img", function (e) {
        alert($(this).closest("[id^=pin]").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: By using your way, the alert will only be shown when the user is clicking on the textArea? Is it possible to alert even if the user clicking on the image?

Comment: Another question is that, since this works fine by hardcoding the id `#pin1`. I guess there should be a way for me to trigger a function dynamically rather than hardcoing the id? using something like `this`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. What if I would like to alert the id instead of a generic hello? I need more control over the element.

Comment: @IsaacLem id of image or `pin` like id

Comment: The id should be `pin1,pin2,......pinN`. On top of that,`#pin1 img` does not working. However the objective can be achieved by removing the `img`.

Comment: @IsaacLem updated answer. If you have more question please make a new question .